# JTextArea: Contar Caracteres

Tags: java

Eclipse | Netbeans | jdk 1.7

Hola a todos

Se requiere contar los Caracteres de un JTextArea; tarea fácil con un contador. Sin embargo también hay que considerar la posibilidad de borrar Caracteres con Retroceso; y es aquí donde se presenta el problema de que en un momento dado cuando ya no hay Caracteres y se sigue pulsando Retroceso, la cuenta se muestra en negativo.

**¿Cómo contar correctamente los Caracteres y evitar la contabilidad negativa?**

Desde ya Muchísimas Gracias

Comment: Hola, puedes poner el codigo que tengas, por favor, eso ayudaria a poder responder tu pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Como no pusiste codigo no te puedo aconsejar segun lo que escribiste,pero una solucion sencilla que se me ocurre seria la siguiente:

```
TextArea text=new TextArea();//tu text area
```

y en el momento que necesites obtener la cantidad de caracteres haria lo siguiente:

```
text.getText().length();//obtener cantidad de caracteres de la cadena devuelta por el text
```